# Java and Visual Studio redistributable package

Tags: java, vcredist

It has come to my attention that there is a link between java and Visual Studio redistributable package.Some versions of java may require different versions of redist. Can some one explain this to me. It seems i don't find anything relevant on the internet

Comment: Any application made with C++ (The Java Runtime included) for Windows requires the Visual C++ Runtime

Comment: Is somewhere an official document for this? Is somewhere a list saying which java version which redistributable needs?